# How to remove the Google Chrome title bar on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, titlebar

How can I remove the "Google - Google Chrome" header that appears in the image below?

[image: Google Chrome window]

I would be glad for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Chrome settings by clicking the three dots at the top right. Under *Appearance*, turn off the option that says *Use system title bar and borders*.

Comment: thank you very much, it worked